# Unable to mount 571 GB Volume

Tags: linux-mint

I have two drives: C and D, and have just removed drive C (contained Windows files). Then I installed Linux Mint.

Mint's working fine, but I do not have access to my drive D. All of my personal and important files are there.

But when I try to open and mount drive D, it shows this error:

```
Unable to mount 571 GB Volume
Error mounting /dev/sda4 at /media/saeed/C064AD3264AD2BDA: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sda4" "/media/saeed/C064AD3264AD2BDA"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda4': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

I've read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation/145904#145904?newreg=13fdc0f9867a4f058d7e4caa34dcc379) question and its answer. It worked, but it's read-only. 
Also I've done what is said in Best Answer of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47538/how-to-make-read-only-file-system-writable) question, but it did not make it rewritable.

What can I do? Or should I do?

I have access no more to Windows. It was Windows 10.

Regards

Comment: You shoulm't want to write to ntfs with linux. Read the files from the ntfs filesystem and throw it away (honest advice).

Comment: Sorry @ctrl-d, I did not get you. I want access my files now, no matter whether it's ntfs, ext4, etc.

Comment: Mount it with the 'ro' option, and you can probably access your files. Copy these to another (linux formatted) disk.

Comment: It's ro, so it's read-only. I've said I've done sth that it's read-only, but I want those files to copy my linux home directory. Even using re-writable commands as another question did not work.

Comment: mount -t "ntfs" -o "ro,uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sda4" "/media/saeed/C064AD3264AD2BDA"

Comment: XXX dev # mount -t "ntfs" -o "ro,uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sda4" "/media/saeed/C064AD3264AD2BDA"
ntfs-3g-mount: failed to access mountpoint /media/saeed/C064AD3264AD2BDA: No such file or directory
XXX dev # cd /media/saeed
XXX saeed # ls
XXX saeed #

Comment: when I go to /media/saeed, it shows nothing

Comment: Try this (as root): mkdir /mnt/disk; mount -t "ntfs" -o "ro,uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" /dev/sda4 "/mnt/disk"

Comment: @ctrl-d The recommendation to not write to NTFS would be valid about 20 years ago, but since then `ntfs-3g` has matured and what you are saying is no longer valid. The OP has to let Windows cleanly shut down drive D:, then it will be accessible to Linux.

Comment: inna saeed # mkdir /mnt/disk; mount -t "ntfs" -o "ro,uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/mnt/disk"
mount: can't find /mnt/disk in /etc/fstab
inna saeed # mkdir /media/saeed; mount -t "ntfs" -o "ro,uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/media/saeed"
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/media/saeed’: File exists
mount: can't find /media/saeed in /etc/fstab

Comment: I've done both /mnt/disk and /media/saeed, both shows errors

Comment: OP has no windows anymore

Comment: @ajeh I've no Windows anymore. ctrl-d: ntfs-3g /dev/sda4 /mnt/disk
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda4': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.

Comment: Free Windows VMs are available from Microsoft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How to mount NTFS drive on linux, and reset the dirty bit.**

Lets do this correctly. It is easy to inadvertently destroy the wrong data.

**1: Identify the HD partition.**

`sudo fdisk -l`

You must be able to pick the drive and partition in question from the info supplied.

Something like this:

```
/dev/sda1            2048    59414527    29706240    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2        59414528   169236479    54910976   83  Linux
/dev/sda3       173432832   488280063   157423616    5  Extended
/dev/sda4       169236480   173432831     2098176   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda5       173434880   488280063   157422592    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

On ***my*** system `/dev/sda5` is the partition with the dirty bit set.

Yours may be `/dev/sda4`.

***Note:***

The X in `/dev/sdXn` is the letter assigned to the physical hard-drive.

The n in `/dev/sdXn` is the number assigned to the partition.

The letters `C:` and `D:` are Microsoft assignments, and do not help here.

Please be sure you are working on the correct drive and partition.

Post the output of `sudo fdisk -l` for help identifying your disk / partition.

**2: Verify the partition is NOT mounted.**

`mount | grep /dev/sda5`

If you get some output similar to this:

```
/dev/sda5 on /mnt/sda5 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)
```

The partition is mounted.

Unmount with:

`sudo umount /dev/sda5`

***Note:***

Yes you can unmount using the "device file" `/dev/sda5` OR the "mount point" `/mnt/sda5`.

**3: Reset the dirty bit.**

Always check what will be done to your data before you modify the data.

`sudo ntfsfix --no-action /dev/sda5`

If you are content that everything looks okay, modify your data.

`sudo ntfsfix --clear-dirty /dev/sda5`

**4: Mount the partition.**

`sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt/myData`

***Note:***

The defaults that mount uses when a NTFS file system is auto-detected are usually fine.

Adjust mount options if the defaults do not work for you.

`sudo mount -t ntfs -rw /dev/sda5`

Check the man page for exact switches for your mount version.

`man mount`

**6: Add to `/etc/fstab` so partition will auto-mount on restart.**

After you mount the partition and have all of your switches fingered out, get the UUID of the partition you want to auto mount.

`sudo blkid`

Note the UUID number.

`sudo vi /etc/fstab`

Add an entry for your NTFS drive

```
## My data on ntfs
UUID=12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789abc /mnt/myData ntfs defaults 0 2
```

***Note:***

Your UUID number will be unique and different from mine. Using the UUID number will prevent an oops if linux assigns the disk a different `/dev` number for some reason.

Adjust the `defaults` to match your switches.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry can't post comments ... Try `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda4` then mount it.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to fix. It's still read-only. It tried to copy file from Desktop to my drive D, but it said: "The destination is read-only.".

Comment: The `ntfsfix` fixed the "unclean file system". Now mount the drive r/w.

Comment: Perhaps adjust the syntax of ntfsfix. `sudo ntfsfix --clear-dirty /dev/sda4`. /`dev/sda4` must be unmounted first.